# How to get a range from start & end index with Office.js while developing MS Word Add-in

Tags: ms-word, office-js, word-addins

I want to get a sub range by character index from the parent paragraph. What's the suggest way to do so? The only method I found to shrink the range is "Paragraph.search()"

ref: 
Word.Range: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.range?view=office-js
Word.Paragraph: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.paragraph?view=office-js

My use case:

I'm writing a markdown plugin for MS Word and I'm trying to parse the following paragraph.

```
A **bold** word
```

The output from markdown parser is {style:"strong",start:2,end:9}. So I want to apply bold style to the targeting range.

Comment: The requirement isn't quite clear. Could you please provide more context, using the [edit] llnk below the question. Are you generating this document content, or working with an existing document? How do you know a particular range has a particular "index" (character count)? Please provide some relevant code...

Comment: Thanks. I'm sorry that I messed up the format while pasting from my notes. I found a solution just now. Posted the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

The existing answer didn't work for me (it seems like `getTextRanges()` no longer accepts empty strings).

So I have adapted the answer to use `paragraph.search()` instead.

```js
async function getRangeByIndex(paragraph: Word.Paragraph, start: number, end: number) {
    const charRanges = paragraph.search('?', { matchWildcards: true })
    charRanges.load()
    await charRanges.context.sync()

    const targetRange = charRanges.items[start].expandTo(charRanges.items[end])
    targetRange.load()
    await targetRange.context.sync()

    return targetRange
}
```

Comment: this is getting range number to number how can we get range from style html or text to text

Comment: @MJunaid My office-js knowledge is somewhat rusty, but iirc you can use `.getRange('start')` to get the start range, then use `.expandTo(endRange)` to get the final `Range`. If this doesn't help you, please ask a new question, as this question asks specifically about getting a range from start and end index

Comment: please check my questions 

https://stackoverflow.com/q/77170293/22285621

Answer (score 1):

Found a way just now. The key is passing an empty separator to `Paragraph.getTextRanges([""])`  I'm not sure how bad the performance would be.

```js
const makeBold = async (paragraph:Word.Paragraph,start:number,end:number) => {
  const charRanges = paragraph.getTextRanges([""])
  charRanges.load()
  await charRanges.context.sync()
  const targetRange = charRanges.items[start].expandTo(charRanges.items[end])
  targetRange.load()
  await targetRange.context.sync()
  targetRange.font.bold = true
  await targetRange.context.sync()
}
```