Precision editing a Word document from MS Word Add-in
I am implementing a precision editing feature for my Microsoft Word Add-in, but can't figure out how to edit a part of a range without making changes to the entire range.
For example I can get each word in a paragraph using:
const words = paragraph.getTextRanges([" "], true); // trimSpacing set to true so it is the words only

Let's say the paragraph is:

hello, world!

Then each of the words' .text would be:

hello,
world!

I want to be able to modify each word, for example update the casing in the word hello, to Hello, or remove the exclamation mark from the second word world! to word.
So when the document is in the "Reviewing" state, after I make the changes from my add in the paragraph should appear like this:

What is the smallest possible range that you can select? All my problems would have been solved if I could select all individual characters by doing something like:
const characters = paragraph.getTextRanges([""]);

But this throws an error:
  {
    "message": "InvalidArgument",
    "error": {
      "name": "RichApi.Error",
      "code": "InvalidArgument",
      "traceMessages": [],
      "innerError": null,
      "debugInfo": {
        "code": "InvalidArgument",
        "message": "InvalidArgument",
        "errorLocation": "Paragraph.getTextRanges",
        "statement": "var textRanges = v.getTextRanges(...);",
        "surroundingStatements": [
          "var v = context.root._getObjectByReferenceId(\"02A!000030C5\");",
          "// >>>>>",
          "var textRanges = v.getTextRanges(...);",
          "// <<<<<",
          "// Instantiate {textRanges}",
          "textRanges.load([\"*\"]);"
        ],
        "fullStatements": [
          "Please enable config.extendedErrorLogging to see full statements."
        ]
      },
      "httpStatusCode": 400
    },


Can you use paragraph.search as in one of the answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56796308/how-to-get-a-range-from-start-end-index-with-office-js-while-developing-ms-wor ? Trouble AFAICR a number of these things only work when you're using the desktop version of Word, not the online version.

Thanks @jonsson this is the workaround that I was looking for!
